# String to float conversion error in python code

Tags: python, string, type-conversion

I am getting the following conversion error and not sure where is the actual problem.

**Exercise:
Write a function that accepts two positive integers which are the height and width of a rectangle and returns a list that contains the area and perimeter of that rectangle.**

```
def Area_of_a_Rectangle(width, height):
    '''Calculate the area'''
    Area = width * height

    # calculate the Perimeter'''
    Perimeter = 2 * (width + height)
    print("\n Area of a Rectangle is: ",Area)
    print(" Perimeter of Rectangle is: ",Perimeter)

width = float(input("Please Enter the Width of a Rectangle: "))  # This line errs out.
height = float(input("Please Enter the Height of a Rectangle: "))
Area_of_a_Rectangle(width, height)

**Error:**
Error in executing student function:
ValueError at line 11
could not convert string to float:
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Regarding your [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), please don't use line-numbers. If you want to mark out a specific line, then do it with a comment in the code you show. Also please read [the post formatting help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help), to learn how you could properly format your code snippets. Now please edit your question to improve it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the entered value. If you enter a numeric value, line 11 should not give that error.

Comment: The code is working fine in IDLE but same code is giving error in the editor of my python course site http://courses.edx.org

Comment: Maybe they are specific about using `int`s and not `float`s? Just a guess, I can't probably figure out what's going on someone else's program (that website) without any knowledge.